# XCode and recent iOS SDK

Tags: iphone

I am currently using `XCode 3.2.2 and iOS SDK 3.2`. With these I can produce binary which works on iPhone 3.1.3. If I upgrade to `XCode 3.2.4 and iOS 4.1`, would I still be able to build binaries for iPhone 3.1.3 device? If no, can I install both, or it's tricky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eiko is correct, what's more I believe that apple will no longer accept applications built with pre 4.x SDK.

To get this set up you need to change the following settings

- Set the "Base SDK" in your projects settings to the newest version number of iOS whose features you may want.
- Set the "iPhone OS Deployment Target" to the oldest version number of iOS that you will support.

*Courtesy of [CocoaWithLove](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/07/tips-tricks-for-conditional-ios3-ios32.html)*

Regarding installing multiple versions, it's not tricky... just awkward. The release versions of XCode are installed into the `/Developer` directory. To install multiple versions you need to move the `/Developer` directory to something else e.g. `/OldXCode` and then install the new version (Which is put into `/Developer`)

Hope that helps

Comment: Actually you don't need to move the /Developer directory elsewhere, just install another versions of Xcode into different directories. As per my setup, /Developer is for Xcode beta, /DeveloperStable is for the stable one, and /Xcode4 is obviously for Xcode 4.

Answer (score 1):

You can, and you should, always use the latest SDK.

You can easily build agains 4.1 and still target 3.x - in fact most developers do this at the moment.